# Regex for text between items

Tags: regex

I'm having a hard time pulling out just the 1069 value using regex.  I think I might be trying to use unsupported features to make it worse.

**Q1**: Would someone be able to let me know what regex would be needed to pull the numbers the 4th and 5th colons (*value of 1069*)

**Q2**: How to pull the items after the 6th colon? (*value of 2929*)

**sample text:**

```
diamond:dev:liquid:beta:1069:zone:2929
```

Comment: Can you use a function that splits strings based on a delimiter and returns an array?

Comment: You don't need a regex. Just split by `:`

Comment: Just split by `:` and get the 6th item ?

Comment: Split isn't an option in this scenario, I'd need to do a regex.

Comment: Ill have to ask this in a different forum, "What does regex mean" doesn't have anything to do with the current specific question and issue Im listing as a non programmer.  Thanks for your input people who mentioned split!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer 1: How to get value between 4th and 5th colons:

```
(?>[^:]+:){4}([^:]+)
```

Try at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1jj9Ne/2)

Answer 2: How to get value after the 6th colon:

```
(?>[^:]+:){6}([^:]+)
```

Try at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nrto9q/1)

Note: You can replace `+` with `*` to handle cases like `::::2:` (empty between colons).